# Check if structure is not in vector

Tags: c++, struct, stdvector

I have a vector of structs. I need to check if the struct is or is not in the vector. The entire struct, not any specific member. It throws me this error upon compile time:

```
binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'NavigationNode'
(or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

My struct:

```
 struct NavigationNode{ 
    int x, y; //their x and y position on the grid
    float f, g, h;
    int parentGCost;
    int value;
};

NavigationNode currentNode;
```

The vector

```
vector<NavigationNode> openList;
```

My find:

```
 if (find(closedList.begin(), closedList.end(), currentNode) == closedList.end() )
 {
 }
```

Comment: What determines equality between two `NavigationNode` objects?

Comment: whether they have the same values of the struct members

Comment: @meWantToLearn - see the comment of DavidRodríguez-dribeas under the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to write an equality operator for your custom type. Assuming all variables have to be the same for two `NavigationNode` objects to be the same, it should look something like this:

```
bool floatEqual(float a, float b)
{
     // adapt this comparison to fit your use-case - see the notes below
     static const int EPSILON = 0.00001;    // arbitrarily chosen - needs to be adapted to the occuring values!
     return std::abs(a – b) <= EPSILON;
}

bool operator==(NavigationNode const & a, NavigationNode const & b)
{ 
    return a.x == b.x &&
        a.y == b.y &&
        floatEqual(a.f, b.f) &&
        floatEqual(a.g, b.g) &&
        floatEqual(a.h, b.h) &&
        a.parentGCost == b.parentGCost &&
        a.value == b.value;
}
```

Even if you could also do it as a member function of `NavigationNode`, the recommended way is to implement the `operator==` as a free function (that way, both parameters can take advantage of any possible implicit conversions).

Note on float comparison: Due to how floating point numbers are represented, it is not a trivial task to compare them. Just checking for equality might not give the desired results. See e.g. this question for details:
[What is the most effective way for float and double comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison)

Comment: `a.x = b.x` is an assignment

Comment: Comparing floating point for equality can be tricky, unless it was a copy of the original, the floating point numbers might be mathematically equivalent (obtained by operations that mathematically end up yielding the same value) and yet compare as different

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - nice point, I was just writing the same.

Comment: @nyarlathotep - usually, `fabs`, combined with subtraction and comparing to `e`psilon (very small positive floating point number, like `.0001` or something; depending on the necessary precision) is a nice approach.

Answer (score 5):

You need to overload `operator==`.

As global function:

```
bool operator==( const NavigationNode& lhs, const NavigationNode& rhs )
{
    // compare lhs and rhs
}
```

Or as member function:

```
bool operator==( const NavigationNode& other ) const
{
    // compare this & other
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to overload the comparison operator.
If your intention of "==" is "are each of the values contained in my struct equal to the corresponding members in this other struct" then you can write that.

```
bool operator==(const NavigationNode& lhs, const NavigationNode& rhs)
{
    return /* compare each member in here */
}
```